# How to use thread in android to draw arc that grows timely?

Tags: android, multithreading, graphics

I am trying make application as like countdown timer. I want to draw the arc as time passes. Using Thread i am trying to do that but its not getting drawn as thread runs. `

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView drawingImageView;


      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        drawingImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.DrawingImageView);

        Paint paint;
        Canvas canvas;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        // Circle

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(15);


        RectF rectF = new RectF(20, 20, 200, 200);





        try{

            int deg=10;

            for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){

                canvas.drawArc (rectF, 0, deg, false, paint);

                Thread.sleep(1000);

                deg=deg+10;
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error ! ", 1000).show();
        }

      }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your solution has some issues:

1) you do not have any thread. you just use main thread and do not create any additional thread.

2) you should also read communication between UI thread and main thread at:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

3) you must not sleep on main thread, if you sleep on main thread it is possible to android mark your app as not responding (ANR:application not responding error)

4) if you make any changes in your views you must update widgets to show them by calling `invalidate` or by setting bitmap again.

Demo that make you be sure it is working.

[image]

Here is complete solution to your problem:

your xml :

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.temp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DrawingImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      ImageView drawingImageView;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        drawingImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.DrawingImageView);
        Thread myThread = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

                int deg=10;
                RectF rectF = new RectF(100, 100, 400, 400);
                Paint paint;
                paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(15);


               final  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);


                for(int i=0;i<=35;i++){
                    canvas.drawArc (rectF, 0, deg, false, paint);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        }
                    });
                    deg=deg+10;
                }
            }
    };
        myThread.start();

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Its the same that i want to do.